# Is there a way to use the CSVHelper CSVWriter with Dropbox?

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox-api, csvhelper

I've used CSVHelper with Dropbox previously, but reading files. Now I want to write a file, and have discovered that this is not so simple. i.e. this code, with FolderPath as relative to the Dropbox root folder...

```
using (StreamWriter writer=new StreamWriter(${FolderPath}MyCSVFile.csv"))
using (CsvWriter csv=new CsvWriter(writer,leaveOpen:false)) {csv.WriteRecords(records);}
```

Treats the path as relative to the device's root folder. It's easy to do this with read, because the Dropbox ReadFile returns a string, so all CSVHelper sees is a string, but in this case need to write to a location controlled by Dropbox, which means having to use the Dropbox client.

I worked out how to do it, but as per the suggestion "share your knowledge Q&A style", I'll keep going and answer my own question for anyone else who runs into this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst typing my question, I thought "if only there was a way to get this as a string instead of writing to device", but the CSVHelper doco only showed writing to device, using StreamWriter. So I decided to just click around some of the other Write scenario's, and in the "writing to a Dynamic object" I found in that example that you could use StringWriter instead (I wouldn't have thought to look in there, since I wasn't working with Dynamic objects!).

So here is my working code (TempSB2 is a StringBuilder that I re-use throughout the code)...

```
TempSB2.Clear();
using (StringWriter writer=new StringWriter())
using (CsvWriter csv=new CsvWriter(writer,leaveOpen:false)) {
    csv.WriteRecords(records);
    TempSB2.Append(writer.ToString());
    }
await DropboxService.WriteFileAsync(DropboxService.StringToStream(TempSB2.ToString()),$"{FolderPath}MyCSVFile.csv");
```